# Resolve and organize imports for all files in given folder

Tags: typescript, import, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

I need to resolve all missing imports for a set of typescript files and to organize the imports (remove unused imports and sort them). In visual studio 2017, I use intellisense to add import (manually for every missing references) and I use `Ctrl+K,D` to organize the imports. I need to do that on 700 files. That's why I'm looking for a way to run those commands on an entire folder (or entire project). My project is an Angular project, so I'm looking for this solution with Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in way to do this yet, so best way I've found to do this is to use the [Folder source actions VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.folder-source-actions)